# There is no action mapped for namespace struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, javabeans

I am converting INR to USD and visa-versa. When I run, I get this warning:

```
WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-22] com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger.warn Could not find action or result
 There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name netbeans-tomcat-status-test. - [unknown location]
```

Action file is ConverterAction.java

```
package com.vishal;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ConverterAction extends ActionSupport {
private String from;
private String to;
private BigDecimal amount;
private BigDecimal result;

public String excecute() {
ConverterBean n = new ConverterBean();
result = n.convert(from, to, amount);
return SUCCESS;
}

public String getFrom() {
return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
this.from = from;
}

public String getTo() {
return to;
}

public void setTo(String to) {
this.to = to;
}

public BigDecimal getAmount() {
return amount;
}

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
this.amount = amount;
}

public BigDecimal getResult() {
return result;
}

public void setResult(BigDecimal result) {
this.result = result;
}
}
```

Bean class ConverterBean.java

```
package com.vishal;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ConverterBean {
private BigDecimal INR = new BigDecimal(0.02291);
private BigDecimal USD = new BigDecimal(46.58);

public BigDecimal convert(String fromCurrency, String toCurrency, BigDecimal     amount) {
if (fromCurrency.equals(toCurrency)) {
  return amount;
}

BigDecimal toRate = findRate(toCurrency);
BigDecimal result = toRate.multiply(amount);
return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
}

public BigDecimal findRate(String currencySymbol) {
  BigDecimal returnValue = null;

  if (currencySymbol.equals("INR")) {
      returnValue=INR;
  }

  if (currencySymbol.equals("USD")) {
    returnValue=USD;
  }
  return returnValue;  
  }
  }
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts  Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
<package extends="struts-default" name="/">
<action name="convert">
  <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<s:form action="convert">
  Enter amount to convert: <s:textfield default="0" name="amount"/>
  <br/><br/>

  From:
  <s:textfield name="from"/>
  <br/><br/>

  To:
  <s:textfield name="to"/>
  <br/><br/>

  <s:submit value="submit"/>
  </s:form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Result.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>    
        <h2>Hello</h2>hi
        <s:property value="result" default="0" />

</body>   
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I'd consider taking a quick spin through a simple tutorial before going much further; besides the formatting issues there's a lot going on here that's not going to work as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much for a comment, so here's your code review.

**ConverterAction**

- Don't import stuff you don't have to.
- Put the important stuff at the top (getters and setters are not important).
- Be consistent with indentation and spacing

```java
package com.vishal;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ConverterAction extends ActionSupport {
  private String from;
  private String to;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private BigDecimal result;

  public String excecute() {
    ConverterBean n = new ConverterBean();
    result = n.convert(from, to, amount);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String getFrom() {
    return from;
  }

  public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
  }

  public String getTo() {
    return to;
  }

  public void setTo(String to) {
    this.to = to;
  }

  public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

  public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }

  public BigDecimal getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public void setResult(BigDecimal result) {
    this.result = result;
  }
}
```

**ConverterBean**

- Use very descriptive variable names.
- Use spaces around language keywords.
- Don't insert random blank lines.
- Return early.
- Handle all cases.

```java
package com.vishal;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ConverterBean {
  private BigDecimal INR = new BigDecimal(0.02291);
  private BigDecimal USD = new BigDecimal(46.58);

  public BigDecimal convert(String fromCurrency, String toCurrency, BigDecimal amount) {
    if (fromCurrency.equals(toCurrency)) {
      return amount;
    }

    BigDecimal toRate = findRate(to);
    BigDecimal result = toRate.multiply(amount);
    return result.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
  }

  public BigDecimal findRate(String currencySymbol) {
      BigDecimal returnValue = null;

      if (currencySymbol.equals("INR")) {
          return INR;
      }

      if (currencySymbol.equals("USD")) {
        return USD;
      }

      throw new UnsupportedOperation("Unknown Conversion");
  }
}
```

**JSP**

- Struts 2 properties exposed by their *property* name, e.g., lower-case.
- Formatting is important.
- Actions are not classnames, they're action names: You don't even have a valid `struts.xml` at the moment, as your server log must indicate.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <s:form action="convert">
      Enter amount to convert: <s:textfield default="0" name="amount"/>
      <br/><br/>

      From:
      <s:textfield name="from"/>
      <br/><br/>

      To:
      <s:textfield name="to"/>
      <br/><br/>

      <s:submit value="submit"/>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
  <package extends="struts-default" name="/">
    <action name="convert">
      <result name="success">/result.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

(The config is from memory, it's been awhile.)

You'll also have an issue when you first request the page since there will be no values, so you'll get `null` all over the place.

Comment: Thank you Dave for taking time out to help me out.. but i m Still getting the same error: Could not find action or result
 There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name netbeans-tomcat-status-test. - [unknown location]

Comment: @VishalTorne I'd open a new question with your actual code and config; impossible to diagnose with old information.

Comment: Hi Dave I appreciate your help thank you.. I have just updated the question and added my `result.jsp` file. I get same warning and values doesn.t seem to bind with properties.

Comment: @VishalTorne The current error seems more an issue with Netbeans than S2 in general, unless you're specifically requesting `netbeans-tomcat-status-test`.

Comment: Hey I have changed my server to Glassfish.. the error is not there.. but i am not getting the value converted in the result.jsp.. It is 0. will i have to use bean tag or something or I have done some mistake thats not letting the bean values to bind.. thanks for your time. @Dave